# Elasticsearch: sort inner hits using query ordering

Tags: elasticsearch

I have indexed a bunch of documents, each of which contains tags as nested documents, which I get back as `"inner_hits"`.  My query and the nested documents are keyword tokenized, and I'm only interested in exact matches between them.

I want elasticsearch to return me the documents that have matches, and to sort the `"inner_hits"` *based on the order the query terms matched the nested documents*.  Is this possible?

For example, imagine I have the document "ferrari" with the tags `red` and `car`. if I search for the query "red sports car", I want ES to return me the document "ferrari" with nested documents "red" and "car" in that order.

This is so that when my user searches for "red sports car", I can say:

> Found **ferrari** matching **red car**

I don't want to say:

> Found **ferrari** matching **car red**

Can this be done? At the moment I get back the inner hits sorted by score, and apparently I can change this using `sort`, but I don't know how to refer to the ordering of the query.

Here are the mappings:

```
{
  "vehicles": {
    "mappings": {
      "vehicle": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "tags"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the shape of the doc:

```
{
  "_index": "vehicles",
  "_type": "vehicle",
  "_id": "b1013ec8b8",
  "_source": {
    "name": "ferrari",
    "tags": [
      {
        "name": "car"
      },
      {
        "name": "red"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's the query:

```
{  
  "query":{  
    "nested":{  
      "path":"tags",
      "query":{  
        "terms":{  
          "tags.name":[  
            "red",
            "sports",
            "car"
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits":{  
        "size":100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've had to heavily edit these to show what's going on, so apologies if they aren't syntactically correct, they should show the gist.

Comment: Can You share the sample document. and  What query did you run?

Comment: I've added the doc, mappings and query.

Comment: Hi did you have any luck finding a solution to this?

Comment: I’ll be honest it’s too long ago for me to remember clearly, but I don’t think I did. I wrote a blog post showing how I achieved what I was after though, maybe there’s something that can help in there? http://conan.is/blogging/weighted-elasticsearch.html